# woocommerce - Product page reviews error

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress

I am facing a weird error after working on woocommerce templates. Issue is that I am seeing same reviews (reviews belonging to one particular product) across all the products, what ever the product page I open the reviews are same that of one particular product.I tried trashing that one product but the pattern has not changed and reviews are caught up from another product.

**What I changed:**

Initially my aim was to load the woocommerce templates from the custom plugin I am working based on woocommerce, I have copied the woocommerce templates into my plugin folder and used below code to call each template file separately.

```
function intercept_wc_template_meta($template, $template_name, $template_path) {
if ($template_name == 'single-product/meta.php') {
    $template = um_product_path.'woocommerce/single-product/meta.php';
}

return $template;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template', 'intercept_wc_template_meta', 20, 3);
```

**What came up:**

After doing this for all the files I tried testing with `var_dump($template)` and all the files are loading from my plugin successfully.
Finally there is an error in reviews part of product page.

For example if I have products A, B, C, D and there are 4 reviews for product A which are shown properly on product A page, the same 4 reviews of A are being displayed/overwritten for B, C, D also instead of their own reviews.
Have anyone faced this problem earlier? I am no sure what caused this error.

Comment: hi, did anyone face this issue? any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Consider to find out on which hook `meta.php` template part is added to page, unhook that and try to attach this template part on the same hook with late binding that is using priority > 10. `woocommerce_locate_template` does not work for every thing.

Comment: What you wrote could be suitable for realigning the product page elements by unhooking and hooking to a different place I guess. My problem actually occurred after I called all the template files from my custom plugin folder.

Comment: not necessarily different place , you can use this on same space but It is only helpful if you want to modify a template part or a template conditionally .

Comment: You are right but my issue is different from what you are saying